# Exported ova failed to import in xcp-ng center

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, xen

I have exported a centos7 ova file and I am trying to import it into XCP-ng 8.0 using XCP-ng center 8.0.1. But This error shows.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, error messages within X* Center are often worthless.  Help -->  "View XCP-ng Center Log Files" have more details.

Import the OVA using XOA.

Do you have a default storage repository set?

```
[20:55 xcp-ng-gv2b7y1 ~]# xe pool-param-get uuid=TabCompleteMe param-name=default-SR
<not in database>  #BAD, many things will not work.#
```

So if you have `<not in database>`, there is no default Storage Repository.  Follow Olivier directions at [Set the XenServer default SR](https://xen-orchestra.com/blog/set-the-xenserver-default-sr/).

Lastly, the command line interface provides the most power and with tab completion of parameters and even UUIDs, it is not as daunting as you would think.  Yes, just typing the first few numbers of a UUID and tap the tab key for auto-complete.

```
[20:48 xcp-ng-g ~]# xe help vm-import
            command name            : vm-import
                    reqd params     :
                    optional params : filename, preserve, sr-uuid, force, host-username, host-password, type, remote-config, url, vdi:
                    description     : Import a VM. If type=ESXServer is given, it
    will import from a VMWare server and 'host-username', 'host-password' and
    'remote-config' are required. Otherwise, it will import from a file, and 
    'filename' is required. If the option preserve=true is given then as many 
    settings as possible are restored, including VIF MAC addresses. The default is 
    to regenerate VIF MAC addresses. The VDIs will be imported into the Pool's 
    default SR unless an override is provided. If the force option is given then any 
    disk data checksum failures will be ignored. If the parameter 'url' is 
    specified, xapi will attempt to import from that URL.
```

Comment: Please add tag info and excerpt for the new tag you created